# Will ASP.NET MVC replace ASP.NET Web Forms in future?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008

I am working in ASP.NET Web Application. I dont know about MVC and ASP.NET MVC. I read that ASP.NET and ASP.NET MVC are different. 
I am a beginner in ASP.NET.
Now Everyone has asked me about ASP.NET MVC.
So I had a confusion whether to learn ASP.NET or to learn ASP.NET MVC.
In future, Which one will be prefered in the market whether ASP.NET or ASP.NET MVC?
I need all your suggestions please.

Comment: I am assuming that you are talking about ASP.NET MVC vs ASP.NET WebForms. as far as I can tell, the 1 won't replace the other, there are cases where both are useful and it comes down to preference really. It gives developer's a choice. This is what we as developers want.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/894865/is-asp-net-mvc-destined-to-replace-webforms

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know whether Microsoft will stop developing ASP.NET WebForms, most probably not. But this is not the case. They do not need to replace each other. WebForms have some strength when you want to show built website to your boss in less than minutes - it is good for small web sites that will not be developed much and made complex. But all the asp.net community agree that ASP.NET MVC is more modern and better suited for web development than WebForms - because of unit testing, more control over generated html, etc. Generally MVC pattern fits the web development very well. I would suggest you to learn ASP.NET MVC. Moreover, you don't need much knowledge from ASP.NET WebForms to learn ASP.NET MVC. Even the very same site you are on, is built on ASP.NET MVC 3

Answer (score 2):

Please listen to this podcast by Scott Hansleman (a well respected technologist and MS employee):

http://www.hanselminutes.com/default.aspx?showID=273

I do not think that ASP.NET web forms are going anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

As archil said, its better to learn ASP.Net MVC over ASP.Net Web forms. I sincerely feel that, it would be very hard and time taking to shift from traditional ASP.Net to ASP.Net MVC after being proficient in ASP.Net web forms kind of development. You will start to feel that ASP.Net MVC is not suited for any of the  projects you develop, if you are proficient in ASP.Net Web forms kind of development. It will take a lot of time to understand and identify the actual benefits of ASP.Net MVC kind of development. **But one should have enough basic knowledge on the traditional ASP.Net development too.**